# opacity: 0 + pointer-events: none vs display: none

Tags: css, animation, opacity, display

I'm designing a dropdown menu with css and I'm wondering, is there any downside with using `opacity: 0` + `pointer-events: none`  instead of using `display: none` ?

I wanna do fade in/out when hovering. but `dispaly` way makes it instantaneous. and don't wanna do any javascript. so,

- is there any way to make `display: none` after animation end without javascript ?
- is there any side effect of using `opacity: 0` + `pointer-events: none` instead of `display: none`?

```css
    #trigger{background-color: red}

    a{
        opacity: 0; 
        transition: 500ms 200ms; 
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    #trigger:focus +ul a{opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: all
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button id=trigger>Trigger</button>
    <ul>
        <a href="#">a<br></a>
        <a href="#">b<br></a>
        <a href="#">c<br></a>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this shows the problem. I can't hover or see them when it is hidden, that's what I want. but when you press tab-tab-tab, you can get them.
(click Trigger for revealing menu, click another place to hide)

Comment: This question is a bit lacking in focus-- you're asking several questions in a single post.  To answer your question regarding `opacity: 0` and `pointer-events: none`: one major issue with this is that keyboard-only users would still be able to focus your element, so it would be effectively always available/visible to them.  And removing keyboard interactivity to achieve this effect would be basically making the app inaccessible, so I'd recommend against that approach if it was the next thing you'd consider.

Comment: thanks for this info! I'll try to avoid this. Can you say something about implementing fade animation and making it display none ?

Comment: If you include a [mcve] I can probably show you how it would work with your code.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I've added. for sake of simplicity, it is done with focus instead of hover.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that leverages `display: none` and `opacity`, and eliminates the need for any `pointer-events` setting.  We are also relying on [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) over the `transition` property. How it works:

1. The anchors start as transparent (`opacity: 0`) and `display: none`; the latter property hides it completely from the DOM layout flow and accessibility tree
2. When we focus the `#trigger`, we set the anchors as `display: block` and we apply an `animation` defined by `@keyframes animatein` to them
3. The `animatein` animation we've defined moves the anchors from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` over the `animation-duration` value defined in the `#trigger:focus+ul a` declaration.

```css
#trigger {
  background-color: red
}

a {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

#trigger:focus+ul a {
  animation-name: animatein;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes animatein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button id=trigger>Trigger</button>
  <ul>
    <a href="#">a<br></a>
    <a href="#">b<br></a>
    <a href="#">c<br></a>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

You might need to tweak this a bit to fit your needs, but hopefully this puts you on the right path.

Comment: this works... but 1 way. when you go out of focus, it hides instantly. not smooth like in my example.